# error while trying to connect to mongodb the first time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, visual-studio, terminal, path

I ran this command while trying to connect to mongodb after installing for the first time..& got this error. Can someone help me on this? Thanks.

```
PS C:\Users\n_ambati\node-course> /Users/n_ambati/mongodb/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath=/Users/n_ambati/mongodb-data                          2020-01-15T09:58:24.520-0500 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling 
TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-01-15T09:58:24.970-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=17080 port=27017 dbpath=/Users/n_ambati/mongodb-data 64-bit host=DIXITAL103
2020-01-15T09:58:24.971-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2020-01-15T09:58:24.971-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.2
2020-01-15T09:58:24.971-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a0bbbff6ada159e19298d37946ac8dc4b497eadf
2020-01-15T09:58:24.971-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-01-15T09:58:24.971-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-01-15T09:58:24.971-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-01-15T09:58:24.971-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2012plus
2020-01-15T09:58:24.971-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-01-15T09:58:24.971-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-01-15T09:58:24.971-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/Users/n_ambati/mongodb-data" } }
2020-01-15T09:58:24.974-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /Users/n_ambati/mongodb-data not found., terminating
2020-01-15T09:58:24.974-0500 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-01-15T09:58:24.974-0500 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-01-15T09:58:24.974-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-01-15T09:58:24.975-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
PS C:\Users\n_ambati\node-course>
```

Comment: Is there a reason to specify a `--dbpath` ? it might not matter much but it would be ideal to use default db path of mongo if you're new to mongo :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path doesn't exist: "/Users/n_ambati/mongodb-data".
Apparently "C:\Users\n_ambati\node-course" does exist so I think you just need to create the folder "mongodb-data" in the "n_ambati" folder and you are good to go.

Comment: Oops, rookie mistake. Created mongodb-data folder & it worked. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. If you could validate my answer so your question is marked as resolved, it would be awesome :-).